# Create Oracle user to do backup job

Tags: oracle

For the security reason, I want to create the user and then assign the backup job to that user. This means that this user is not allowed to do anything else beside backing up the database.

However, as the Oracle documents says that user logged in to RMAN must have sysdba privilege. So as the sysdba, that user can perform many other database operations.

So, how can I create a user and assign only a specific backup job?

Regards,

Sarith

Comment: As said in the Oracle documentation, RMAN can only be run with the sysdba privilege.

Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: Because this user can create or drop any objects in the database without restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstand what the sysdba privilege is and how it is managed:
The SYSDBA privilege is needed to perform some operations (create/drop/alter database, start or stop an instance, ...).
When you connect to a database using this privilege, it is as if you were connected as user "sys".

Due to the fact that the SYSDBA privilege is needed to startup the instance, the control of this privilege is manage **outside the database**, ie in a group at the OS level.
This group is named "dba" on unix server or "ora_dba" on windows boxes.
All the OS user accounts that are in this group are allowed to connect to the database with the sysdba privilege, even if they don't have an account inside the database.

And as said in the documentation RMAN **must** be run with the sysdba privilege.
Indeed, this user is allowed to drop any objects in the database without restriction but this is because RMAN should be run only by a dba not by some random users.

If you want to allow a user to export some objects you will have to do otherwise. If you use oracle 10g or newer, have a look at datapump.
With datapump, a DBA can choose a folder on the server, where some users could export some objects.